# move the upper image layout with animation to get down image click

Tags: android

I have two images overlapping each other, i am animating(sliding) the above image to the right of the screen up to some part of it remaining on the screen so that i can animate it back to its original position, Now i want to get click of the below image to start my new activity but i am getting the click of above image only, and i know that animating the upper image will not move its layout. 
But i have tried to move the layouts of upper image but after moving the layouts the above image disappears.

Any help?

Comment: Which layout are you using as parent layout?

Comment: try to use frame layout it will give focus to the content lying below another content if it is visible

Answer (score 0):

After translating the above image,set its clickability to false,like
  aboveImage.setClickable(false);
Try the below code ,it will work

### AnimationActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
     ImageView aboveImage;
     ImageView belowImage;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         aboveImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_above);
         belowImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_below);
        aboveImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                /*belowImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_to_right,R.anim.move_to_left);*/
                Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100,0, 0);
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                aboveImage.startAnimation(animation);
                aboveImage.setVisibility(0);
                aboveImage.setClickable(false);



            }
        });
        belowImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

### main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_below"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cherry" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_above"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/amalapaul" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it will give me the click of down image but i want the click of upper image also to reverse the animation. by using aboveImage.setClickable(false) i will loose it ......